# How to find subgraphs in a directed graph without converting to undirected graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph that has many subgraphs. I have some edges that connect two nodes in both directions, that is, A-->B and B-->A. The bidirectionality is important, as it represents a lack of knowledge on our part as to whether A goes to B or B goes to A, and we have no easy way of determining which is the correct one.

I'd like to know how many subgraphs there are, and output to a Pandas DataFrame the edges in each subgraph. However, NetworkX only takes in undirected graphs in the provided connected_components_subgraph(G) function. When I convert the graph to an undirected graph, I can use connected_components_subgraph() to get the nodes in each edge, but I lose edge directionality.

Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Are there cycles in your graph? Such that A --> B (--> X) --> A?

Comment: Yes, there are cycles in the graph. Not every subgraph has a cycle, but a good number of them do.

Comment: Okay, and you want to have all the possible subgraphs? So from a graph that contains A --> B and B --> A, you want to create two graphs: One with the edge A --> B and the other with the edge B --> A? Is that right? Else, please clarify your question. Especially that last sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [weakly connected components](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs.html#networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs)?

That algorithm treats the edges as if they were undirected and returns the connected components in that graph.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph([(1,2),(2,1),(3,4)])

In [3]: for w in nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(G):
   ...:     print(w.edges())
   ...:     
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
[(3, 4)]
```

Comment: Yes, that is right! Many thanks Aric, I'm still a newbie to graph theory, so I wasn't able to translate my thoughts correctly into graph theory language. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for that one. But one question: when I assign the output of w_c_c_s() to a variable "subg" and then iterate over that one, its content seems to be "consumed" after the iteration. Why is that?! When I execute the print-loop twice, it does not print anything on the second run.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **SCC** of the graph, that are **strongy**  **connected**  **component** s. They can be found with a variant of **DFS** (depth first search).

You should take a look at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) article.

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You want want to find all nodes `x` where there is a `y` in `neighbour(x)`, so that `x` is element of `neighbour(y)`? That's what you want?