# How to extract a subgraph from a dot file

Tags: graphics, networkx, graphviz, dot, subgraph

I have a dot file generated by a software called egypt. The dot file contains many nodes and edges. If I use this dot file to draw a picture, it is very hard see the picture clearly as there are too many nodes. And what I need is only a subgraph starting from a node, and I don't need the whole picture.

Is there any way to draw a subgraph from a specified node (such as start_node) using this dot file?

Comment: `gvpr` should do the trick

Comment: For example like [here](https://gist.github.com/blabber/74b8d9ed59d0b2ad0d7a734113996424)

Comment: I find the answer in this post of stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935510/networkx-digraph-create-subgraph-digraph-by-node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NetworkX DiGraph create subgraph (DiGraph) by node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935510/networkx-digraph-create-subgraph-digraph-by-node)