# Python - Networkx: How to draw all connected components from a node?

Tags: python, networkx

I am quite new to Networkx and wanted to know how I can filter a node and draw a graph with all its connected components.

A sample example of my data is below:

| From | To | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | $200 |
| a | c | $100 |
| c | a | $400 |
| b | d | $500 |
| e | f | $200 |

For example if i want to see (or rather filter by "a") "a" with its connected component only, how can I draw it to get this output? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Something like [NetworkX DiGraph create subgraph (DiGraph) by node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32935510/15497888)?

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for the response, however, this is either predecessor or successor, I wanted those that are within the same network. Thanks